# Copy, paste, browse

Tags: copy-paste

I recently changes my DPI to 360 on my Nexus 5.

Now when I copy a text it pops a top panel with the copy/paste/...  icons but they have text with them now.

Did android changed something or is it because of the DPI?

Could you guys check your phones and what they show while copying?

Here is a picture (it appears in **any** app):

[image: icons and text]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's because you changed your DPI. In general, if you change some setting on your phone (especially if it's using root) then any resulting change is likely a side-effect of that change.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering but I like it, I really do.